# How to handle concurrent access in mysql?

Tags: mysql, web-services, concurrency, database-concurrency

If a shopping site only has 1 product available and 2 people try to buy it at the same time, who will get the product? How will the server prioritize the user."curious about flash sale on amazon,flip kart". which algorithm?

Answer (score 2):

Followings are what could happen behind the scene and using any modern application framework it is pretty easy to achieve.

I'm assuming that your scenario is:

- Two users logged into your system say they are `U1` and `U2`
- Select a product
- There is only one product is available
- They both clicked Add to Cart/Buy Now/Checkout
- One user will be served and another user will be notified that the product is not available anymore

Suppose `T1` and `T2` are the nanosecond representation of the time when they clicked on the checkout button. The chances that `T1` and `T2` are equals to each other is very low but there is a possibility.

In your case, the web-server will serve both the requests generated by the users in two different threads, `TH1` and `TH2`. It is highly unlikely since there are hundreds of users at any given time present in your system but not impossible that the `TH1` and `TH2` get served by two different core of the CPU, assuming you have more than one core.

Hence both of the `TH1` and `TH2` will try to get a hold onto your Product.

Now you need to have/introduce two attributes (think as MySQL columns) to your `PRODUCT`: `VERSION` and `CHECKED_OUT`.

Both the `TH1` and `TH2` will start their own transaction at the same time, say `TR1` and `TR2`, assuming you have InnoDB as your database engine.

Both of the `TR1` and `TR2` will:

- Read your `PRODUCT` from the database table along with the `VERSION` and `CHECKED_OUT`: `{id: 1, version: 0, checked_out: 0, ...}` and transfer it to the server.
- In the server, both of the `TR1` and `TR2` will increase the `VERSION` value which was read earlier and execute an Update statement stating that `UPDATE PRODUCT SET CHECKED_OUT = 1, VERSION = 1 WHERE ID = 1 AND VERSION = 0`
- DB will lock the row, execute the `UPDATE` and return the number of the modified row in a sequential fashion since the `UPDATE` should be executed within a single thread. Note here, this thread is DB's own thread, not the `TR1` and `TR2`.
- Here if I assume `TR1`, i.e., `TH1` was served before `TR2`, i.e., `TH2` by DB's `UPDATE` thread then business logic that is behind `TR1` will get that the number of rows updated is equaled to 1, whereas that of `TR2` will get 0.
- Which in turn imply that `U1` get to check out the product whereas `U2` will be notified with a nice apologizing message.